Cannot resolve to object VAT111. Type and Subtype X'0201' Authority X'0000'
My 'VAT111' RPGLE program is in the VTAX library and I try to call this VAT111 from the MAUTINV RPGLE program in the QDEVLIB library. I got the issue [Cannot resolve to object VAT111. Type and Subtype X'0201' Authority X'0000'.] How do I fix it?
can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Did you have the VTAX library in list?

How do I check it @Nifriz

EDTLIBL in command line...

Add the library that contains the file to the library list using the ADDLIBLE command.
